# Can I somehow increase the latency / response time of a server for testing?

Tags: latency, speed

I am looking to make some speed performance tests. Normally our server responds within ~25 ms or so, but, I would somehow like to make it answer with delay. So basicly I would like to make some setting that increased the latency to f.ex 50ms, 100ms, 1000ms etc. Numbers do not have to be exactly 50ms,100ms etc, but in the same neighbourhood.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of tools that will do this for you.  A quick google search revealed the following

For linux
http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem
http://bencane.com/2012/07/16/tc-adding-simulated-network-latency-to-your-linux-server/

For MAC OS X
network link conditioner xcode (http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/)

For Windows
http://jagt.github.io/clumsy/index.html
https://www.softperfect.com/products/connectionemulator/

Granted all those look like they need to run on the server themselves.  If you want something transparent you could try this 
http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Basis/WAN+Simulator+Live+CD

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do it logically to increase latency and responce time from server end .

Check with  resources allocated to server like RAM , processor speed decrease this resource as per your requirement .. and further observer latency...